# Trading Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, matching, algorithmic-trading, trading

There is two kind of queue which contains

1. Seller Queue
2. Buyer Queue

Both queue only contains quantity not the price.

But there exist some conditions on the elements of those queue like,

1. All or None: All quantity should be traded or none.
2. Minimum Ticket Size: There is some minimum size of block set by the order.
3. Mix: Which contains both of the above conditions.

we have to match orders from both queue in such way that maximum trading happen.

There is no condition that after processing both queue should be empty.
**Example:**
Bidding Queue: 40,30-40A,100A
Offer Queue:   20A,100,120,40

**Trading Happens In following manner:**

1. 20A and 40

   - Updated Queue:
   - Bidding Queue: 20,30-40A,100A
   - Offer Queue:   100,120,40
2. 100 and 20

   - Updated Queue:
   - Bidding Queue: 30-40A,100A
   - Offer Queue:   80,120,40
3. 30-40A and 80:

   - Updated Queue:
   - Bidding Queue: 100A
   - Offer Queue:   40,120,40
4. 100A and 40 will not happen: as the condition (1) all or none applies.
5. (100A) and (40+(120-(100-40))):

   - Updated Queue:
   - Bidding Queue: Empty
   - Offer Queue:   60,40

Can anybody suggest me which algorithm will take place in this kind of implementation.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not take any offense, but your question reminds me of [this helpful letter](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). It would certainly help if you could present at least something you already had in your mind.

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: Since this problem has been dealt with many times on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, we expect to see your progress using those available solutions.  Simply dumping your problem specification here and asking for an analysis is out of Scope fro Stack Overflow.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

There are no formal common computer science algorithms for this process. If you want to know more you can research "two-sided continuous market microstructures", sometimes also called balanced markets.